# When will int be 64 bits?

Tags: go

According to the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int):

> int is a signed integer type that is at least 32 bits in size. It is a distinct type, however, and not an alias for, say, int32.

But it doesn't say which platform or when it will be larger than int32.

Can anyone give me more details about it? Or where is the source code to handle it? Can I force the compiler to make int 64 bits?

I know I can use int64. This is not a question asking for best practice.

Comment: The information tells you that it can store an int in the range of an 32bit int, but that it’s size can be larger then 32bit if this will have performance benefits. Even if it is larger then 32bit you should not expect that it can represent a larger numeric range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)
>
> There is also a set of predeclared numeric types with
>   implementation-specific sizes:
>
> ```
> uint     either 32 or 64 bits
> int      same size as uint
> ```

---

The size of `int` depends on the compiler writer. It's typically a natural, efficient size for the host machine. For example, 64 bits on amd64 and 32 bits on 386 architectures.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runtime.GOARCH, strconv.IntSize)
}
```

Output:

```
$ uname -p
x86_64
$ go run intsize.go
amd64 64
$
```

---

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wyNm2Hyzl6W

Output:

```
amd64p32 32
```

[The Go Blog: Inside the Go Playground](https://blog.golang.org/playground)

---

Go inherited this from C.

> [The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition, Brian W. Kernighan and
>   Dennis Ritchie](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Kernighan-C-Programming-Language-2nd-Edition/PGM54487.html)
>
> `int`  an integer, typically reflecting the natural size of integers on
>   the host machine

Answer (score 5):

The size of an `int` is implementation-defined, presumably, meaning it would vary from platform to platform depending on the operating system and kernel architecture. This is the case in most programming languages (C, for example).

If you *must* have a 64-bit integer exactly, then, well, the `int64` type exists, which will guarantee that there are exactly 64 bits in your integer. Same with `int32`, `int16`, etc. Otherwise, the documentation recommends using `int`, as the compiler can then optimize the code more easily.

Comment: I know I can use int64. I'm just curious about the edge case. And they are lacking doc for that. I just want at least one real example when it will be larger than int32. This is not a question asking for best practice.

Comment: The docs are pretty clear that it's implementation-defined - the best way to figure out actual examples would be to actually run a bunch of tests on various different environments (similar to [what this person did for C](http://ivbel.blogspot.com/2012/02/size-of-primitive-types-in-c-language.html)).

Comment: @YadSmood there is no edge case. `int` is whatever is the most convenient sized integer for the platform. It will normally be 32 bits on a 32-bit machine, and 64 bits on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: You should use it whenever you're counting things, and there's no requirement to go above 2^32, but there's also no requirement that it is exactly 32 bits (no reliance on bit representation, overflow/wrapping, etc.). This lets the compiler choose whatever will be most efficient.